# Tensorflow: How does tensorflow connect python and C++ in details?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to make some modification to `conv_ops` in tensorflow so that the filters used for the convolution in it only consist of binary numbers.

**What I have done**

Following the suggestion in [this tensorflow issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3291), I didn't create a custom op. Instead, I just copy the code in `conv_ops.cc` and change the names like from

```
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(
Name("Conv2D").Device(DEVICE_GPU).TypeConstraint<Eigen::half>("T"),
Conv2DOp<GPUDevice, Eigen::half>);
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(
Name("Conv2D").Device(DEVICE_GPU).TypeConstraint<float>("T"),
Conv2DOp<GPUDevice, float>);
```

to

```
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(
Name("BinaryConv2D").Device(DEVICE_GPU).TypeConstraint<Eigen::half>("T"),
BinaryConv2DOp<GPUDevice, Eigen::half>);
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(
Name("BinaryConv2D").Device(DEVICE_GPU).TypeConstraint<float>("T"),
BinaryConv2DOp<GPUDevice, float>);
```

After all the modification, I have successfully make a new op the same as `conv_ops`. Then in order to bypass the problem that `functor:sign` in 
`//tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops.h` is not that easy to use as simple functors like `functor:Relu` in `//tensorflow/core/kernels/relu_op_functor.h`. I decide the add an input(`binarized_filter`) to my new op `BinaryConv2D`. In this way I can use op `tf.sign` to safely make a binary filter.

**What my problem is**

Although I have changed the registration in `nn_ops.cc` as

```
REGISTER_OP("BinaryConv2D")
    .Input("input: T")
    .Input("filter: T")
    .Input("binarized_filter: T")
    .Output("output: T")
    .Attr("T: {half, float, double}")
    .Attr("strides: list(int)")
    .Attr("use_cudnn_on_gpu: bool = true")
    .Attr(GetPaddingAttrString())
    .Attr(GetConvnetDataFormatAttrString())
```

and the generated python code becomes:

```
result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("BinaryConv2D", input=input, filter=filter,
                                binarized_filter=binarized_filter,
                                strides=strides, padding=padding,
                                use_cudnn_on_gpu=use_cudnn_on_gpu,
                                data_format=data_format, name=name)
```

I use a sign op inside it to get `binarized_filter`:

```
  import tensorflow as tf
  binarized_filter = tf.sign(filter)
```

I got an error as:

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:926] Invalid argument: Signature mismatch, have: float, float, float->float expected: float, float->float
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:334] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Signature mismatch, have: float, float, float->float expected: float, float->float
     [[Node: conv1/BinaryConv2D = BinaryConv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch, conv1/weights/read, conv1/Sign)]]
E tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc:485] Signature mismatch, have: float, float, float->float expected: float, float->float
     [[Node: conv1/BinaryConv2D = BinaryConv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch, conv1/weights/read, conv1/Sign)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I have checked the value of input types in my graph in `//tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py`. They are right. So I assume the input number defined in C++ is still not correct, but I can find no example or document except the source code that can provide information about how the C++ code and python code of tensorflow is associated. I really want to know if I have missed any part of building an op so in the procedure of my modification.